# django - convert mssql datetime to separate date and time

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have a database with numerous datetime columns that display the data like so -

```
2014-04-04 22:35:00.207
```

I want to have it take those columns and do a few things with them.

A>  Strip out the time so it displays like `2014-04-04`

B>  Strip out the date and reformat to display just the time like so `10:35:00 PM`

Comment: Are these columns in DateTime format?

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, column), CONVERT(TIME, column) FROM dbo.table;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) problem.

```
import datetime
d=datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-04-04 22:35:00.207", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
print ("Date: %s" % (d.date()))
print ("Time: %s" %(d.time()))
print ("Time: %s" %(d.time().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")))
```

Outputs:

```
Date: 2014-04-04
Time: 22:35:00.207000
Time: 10:35:00 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

The representation of a [`models.DateTimeField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) is a [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime). Thus, you can use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) function to obtain particular representations of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You want to play with this for each:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

To do something like:

```
>>> date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2014-04-04 22:35:00.207', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 4, 22, 35, 0, 207000)

>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(date, '%Y')
'2014'
```